# How to install gulp via NPM?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install, node-modules, gulp-sass

Following [this tutorial](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-use-gulp-to-generate-css-from-sass-scss/#122_Install_gulp_in_your_project_devDependencies) to set up app. It seems pretty normal and standard compared to all of the other tutorials that I have found. However, when tried and complete the `1.2.3 step` **Create a `gulpfile.js` at the root of the project:** I am getting this error

> error syntax error near unexpected token `}'

This is the command used in terminal.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
```

Basically all want to do is download gulp so, can run `sass` with my `css` in atom. Any help?

Comment: uhm. that code doesn't belong in the terminal.

Comment: In step 1.2.3 you are missing other lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. The code wasn't for the terminal. I needed to create the file separately. I misread the tutorial. Thanks for the help!